# Replacing non alphabetic characters in a char array with space

Tags: c, arrays

I want to remove/replace non alphabetic characters in a char array but instead of removing it, it replaces it with a *space*.
For example, if I type in `hello123hello` it would ouput as `hello hello`.
I want it to output it as hellohello without the extra spaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char input[80];
    char output[80];

    printf("> ");
    scanf("%s", &input);

    int i = 0;

    while (i < sizeof(input))
    { 
        if (input[i] != '\0' && input[i] < 'A' || input[i] > 'z')
          input[i] = ' ';
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    printf("= %s\n", input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why to you put `i++` inside curly braces ?

Comment: its a bad habit.....

Comment: It's completely obfuscating here since it looks like it's part of a multiline `if`. Could you possibly make this less readable?

Comment: @josephsonFPSgreenovaXD - It is a good habit.

Comment: ` if (input[i] != '\0' && input[i] < 'A' || input[i] > 'z') input[i] = ' ';` - Why the semi-colon at the end of the line and not `)`

Comment: C or C++? Which one are you _actually_ using?

Comment: @EdHeal: A `)` there would be a syntax error. It's the extra, redundant block scope around `i++` that's silly

Comment: C++ and no, im not getting any errors in my IDE

Comment: Ouch, my head hurts. No seriously, you might want to consider reading a good C++ book, since there are a lot of things that have nothing to do with C++. C-style strings instead of `std::string`, `<stdio.h>` instead of `<iostream>`, ... . Basically that's not C++.

Comment: What's your alphabet? I guess you'd have to know your character set and encoding to answer that. Maybe you meant all letter characters. You'd still need to state your character set…unless you want to do it with a standard library. (For example, ï is a letter in some character sets. It is in the alphabet of some languages but not English—even though it is used in English writing.)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider a more C++ way to do things:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    s.erase(remove_if(begin(s), end(s), [](char c){ return !isalpha(c); }));
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Note the following:

1. [`string` + `getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) remove the problems of length overruns on inputs.
2. [`isalpha`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) checks whether a character is alphabetical.
3. The [erase-remove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) idiom handles the tricky left-shifts for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to remove characters from an array, you're going to have to move all the characters with higher indices down one step, to overwrite the character to be replaced.

If you're just going to print the result anyway, it's easier to print the "passing" characters on the fly, one at a time, and suppress the rest by not printing them.

Also, you should use `isalpha()` from `<ctype.h>` to check if a character is alphabetic, your code is very much non-portable since it assumes strange things about the encoding. Don't do that.

Comment: UV'd: I don't know of an encoding that has the upper case and lower case right next to each other.

Comment: Really tiny comment: the question is now tagged C++ (it might have been also tagged C before, not sure), so maybe `<cctype>` instead of `<ctype.h>`?

Comment: @AmiTavory Yeah, but I think the C++ is a mis-tagging. I don't think the OP is using C++.

Comment: @unwind - the OP is using the mongrel C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

Your first job is to replace `input[i] < 'A' || input[i] > 'z'` with `!isalpha(input[i])`: for true portable C and C++ you cannot assume ASCII encoding, and even in ASCII, the upper case and lower case section do not "touch".

And if you want to actually *remove* the characters, you ought to run the loop backwards.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your program like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char input[80];
    char output[80];

    printf("> ");
    scanf("%s", &input);

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (i < sizeof(input))
    {
        if (isalpha(input[i]))
        {
            input[j] = input[i];
            ++j;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    input[j-1] = '\0';

    printf("= %s\n", input);

    return 0;
}
```